# How to pass nil as a param of dictionary<String,AnyObject>

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a Dictionary of type `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` and I need to pass a parameter as nil:

```
let params = [
            "number": nil,
            "description": nil,
            "lang" : "spa",
            "byFee": true,
            "plan" : data.Plan
            ] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

        request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
```

If I do this I get an error:

[image]

So I tried to change the Dictionary to `Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>`

But If I do this then the error comes in the request.HTTBody:

[image]

Comment: What do you need the JSON to contain for those keys?

Comment: By definition any value of a Swift dictionary must not be `nil`. A `nil` value is represented by the absence of the key.

Comment: As a suggestion: copy errors as text, not as images, so that they can be selected/copied/searched more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A null value in JSON is equivalent to `NSNull` in ObjC/Swift:

```
let params : [String : AnyObject] = [
    "number": NSNull(),
    "description": NSNull(),
    "lang" : "spa",
    "byFee": true,
    "plan" : data.Plan,
]
```

Comment: You need `NSNull()`, not `NSNull`.

Comment: @OOPer Thanks! Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
let params = [
        "number": "",
        "description": "",
        "lang" : "spa",
        "byFee": true,
        "plan" : data.Plan
        ] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
```